# Why is my if statement printing my else without error?

Tags: python

I have tried everything I could before asking this question... I am making a little text adventure game, really simple and the only code in it is basically just input(). But when they do something wrong, I want to add an else: and print("Thats not valid!") and go back to example = input(), but my else statement is printing and re-doing input with a correct statement, so its still executing else without any error, can anyone help? I don't know why its doing this and all the examples I have seen this is valid code, and my else statement just executes without checking if it was wrong...

````
    ```python
    if prompt1 == "y":
print("Lets start")
else:
     prompt1 = input()
````

It then executes input again...

Comment: it will be easier to help if you post your code in the question aswell

Comment: please provide a [minimally reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the exact code the indention is wrong.
The if and else of same condition should have same indention:

```
if condition:
    do this
else:
    do this
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Indentation is crucial in Python. Looks as if the indentation of `if prompt1 == "y":` and `print("Lets start")` should be switched. Your code shouldn't even compile as it is.

Comment: My indentation was correct in base code, it seems that it was the ELSE that was indented wrong in my real code, I seemed to have fixed the problem and feel very stupid for posting here now... I will make sure to write questions that have not been written and are solvable with basic indentation.

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved :)